# Why would Oozie fail a job with Error Code LimitExceededException when yarn reports that oozie launcher & mapreduce job have completed successfully?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudera, oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-workflow

There are a few questions similar to this on SO.  However nothing has worked for me.  So I am posting this question.

I am Using CDH 6.2.1

I have a workflow that has map-reduce action.  The map-reduce job creates a lot of counters (I think m/r job produces ~300 counters).

I have set the cdh/yarn/config `mapreduce.job.counters.max` property to 8192.

I have also set the:

- `YARN Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for yarn-site.xml`
- `YARN Service MapReduce Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve)`
- `MapReduce Client Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for mapred-site.xml`

If I run the map-reduce job as a stand-alone yarn job (using `yarn jar` command on the command-line), the job completes successfully.

When I run the job as part of the workflow:

- On Yarn/All Applications Page I see that: the oozie launcher job completes successfully.
- On Yarn/All Applications Page I see that: the map/reduce job completes successfully.
- However oozie fails the job reporting: `LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120`

The configuration for the mapreduce job & oozie launcher as reported by yarn has the setting:

```
<property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name>
     <value>8192</value>
     <final>true</final>
     <source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
```

Oozie web interface System-Info/OS-Env reports that the following HADOOP_CONF_DIR: /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/459-oozie-OOZIE_SERVER/yarn-conf/

In that folder I can see that the mapred-site.xml also has:

```
    <!--'mapreduce.job.counters.max', originally set to '8192' (final), is overridden below by a safety valve-->
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name>
    <value>8192</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
```

However I cannot find that property in the yarn-site.xml.

I am not sure what else I can do at this point...

Answer (score 0):

This is an oozie [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3578) which has been resolved.  However, it is not available in the current version of cloudera.

I am posting this here, in case anyone else has the same issue.